# Multiple independent network bridges in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, vmware-workstation, bridge

I have a situation where I have several network interfaces and need to create 2 separate bridges that are independent of one another with just 2 interfaces per each one vs one big bridge.

Virtual interfaces are involved and presently I can make one bridge from physical to virtual just fine, but I need to make two of them.

Is there a way to do this in Windows 10 Pro?

---

*More details:* If you're interested in what I'm doing, I'm running a gateway server in a virtual machine that has 1 input from the ISP and 1 output to the LAN.  I'm using Speedify to bond multiple connections together for both added speed and a backup connection.  This only runs on Windows and macOS.  I need to push this bonded connection into the virtual machine and then the virtual machine will handle all of the gateway and firewall details going out into the rest of the LAN.